# Leaflet Shiny - event map marker click - open plot

Tags: plot, shiny, leaflet

I have a shinny app that shows some markers on a map. When i Click on a marker I have some informations in a table on a the right panel.The table is corresponding to the ID when I click on the marker.

My probelm is: Is that possible to help me modify the code below, in this way:  I want to show a plot when i click on the marker, and the plot is already done somewhere and his name is "Graph_QJ". There is no link with the table "my data".

THe code working with table, and to be modified to show "Graph_QJ" when i Click on a marker:

```
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(plotly)













shinyUI=dashboardPage(

    # Header
    dashboardHeader(title = "Suivis Pit-Tag - Charriage",titleWidth = 450,
                    dropdownMenuOutput("messageMenu1"),
                    dropdownMenuOutput("messageMenu2"),
                    disable = FALSE),

    # Barre de menu
    dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(id="menu",menuItem("Les sites de mesures", tabName = "sites")
      )
    ), #end dashboard sidebar


    # Corps
    dashboardBody(

    tabItem(tabName = "sites",
            navbarPage(title = '',id = "visuobs", #fluid = TRUE,

                       tabPanel("Synthèse",value = "pr",
                                column(width=7,#premiere colonne
                                       box(width = 12, solidHeader = FALSE, status = "primary",
                                           leafletOutput("map",height = 700)
                                       )
                                ),#end premiere colonne
                                column(width=5,#deuxieme colonne
                                       box(width =12, solidHeader = FALSE, status = "primary",
                                       plotlyOutput('Graph_QJ',height = 400),
                                        p(),
                                        tableOutput("myTable")
                                       )
                                )#end deuxieme colonne

                       ) # end tab panel RR  

                ) # end navbar page
    ) # end tab item
  )
) # end dashboardbody







server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data <- reactiveValues(clickedMarker=NULL)
   #Carto synthese mesures Pit
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({

    map <- leaflet(data=myData) %>%  setView(3.3, 44.9, zoom = 7) %>%
      addLegend(position = "bottomright",
                title="Suivis Pit",
                colors = PALETTES$Suivi$colours,
                labels = c(paste(PALETTES$Suivi$distr,sep="")),
                opacity = 0.8) %>%
      #addTiles('http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}')%>%
      addProviderTiles("Thunderforest.Landscape",
                       options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)) %>% 
      addMarkers(data=myData,popup=myData$LIB_LIEU,icon = ~quakeIcons[GROUP],clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(),
                 layerId = myData$id)


   map




  }) # end renderLeaflet

  output$Graph_QJ <- renderPlotly({


  Graph_QJ



 }) # end plotlyGraph

  # observe si il y a un click sur un shape sur la carto
  observeEvent(input$map_marker_click,{
    print("observed map_marker_click")
    data$clickedMarker <- input$map_marker_click
    print(data$clickedMarker)
    output$myTable <- renderTable({
      return(
        subset(myData,id == data$clickedMarker$id)
      )

    })      


  }) #end 

}




shinyApp(shinyUI, server)
```

Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: Cannot reproduce properly. The external data sources cannot be accessed from my computer. Try this: Remove the `renderPlotly()` part from the server scope and paste it into the observeEvent function instead. Does this work? `observeEvent(input$map_marker_click,{
    print("observed map_marker_click");
    data$clickedMarker <- input$map_marker_click;
    print(data$clickedMarker);
    output$myTable <- renderTable({
      return(
        subset(myData,id == data$clickedMarker$id);
      );
      
    });
        output$Graph_QJ <- renderPlotly({
      Graph_QJ
    })    
  })`

Comment: `Graph_QJ` is your graph object, right? If you want to display several graphs dependent on the clicked marker, you could consider creating a graph for each `id`, store them in an object 'graphStack <- list(...)' and then refer back to it by: `graphStack[[data$clickedMarker$id]]`

Comment: Let's say your **markers** are optical representations of your **items**. For each item, you would like to generate one respective **graph**. The only link between them is the **id**. So, for every **id**, you have an item, a marker and a graph. They all carry the same id if they belong together. When you store these information and keep track of your ids, you can easily work with this approach. :)